# Locating a current Google device location via an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm currently developing a feature packed back end for my Plumbing Business which is built on top of Google Maps. This displays all data i add through the business including job locations and history etc.

Seeing the map is fullscreen most of the time i would love to be able to get my device locations (Workers) as a live location on my map but i am having a very hard time finding the correct API, or even examples of such.

My knowledge extends as far as PHP, Javascript & Jquery and have been able to accomplish a lot so far so i was hoping i could use these skills to grab device locations some how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? or examples or previous history with such a thing.

The CRM lives on a server online.

Thanks Ryann,

Answer (score 1):

Accessing mobile device locations will require an application on those phones to regularly send back their location details.

Android documentation on the [location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) services will guide you in accessing this information.

The application could then send this information over a HTTP POST to your backend web application.